# Rest API to Get data from ADF to Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory, rest

I'm trying to monitor pipeline runs from ADF in a Snowflake table. I've managed to use a REST API to get the data into Power BI but I now need to get the data from ADF to Snowflake. Anyone have any examples that would be of great help. The data I need to get is like Pipeline name, run time, start time, error message etc.

Comment: What kind of latency? (time between log written and appearing in snowflake). The preferred log analysis tool for ADF is Log Analytics - is there some reason you want it in SF? Given that SF appears to prefer batch loads, you could use something like scheduled Azure Automation to extract ADF logs using REST API then insert them into Snowflake, if you can get a snowflake driver working from Azure automation, or if snowflake supports a REST API for insertion. This would need to be scheduled. Or you can write to blob storage and have snowpipe insert them.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below approach.

1. Take Pipeline name, run time, start time, error message etc.. details into pipeline variables
2. Inside copy activity, Source - point to some dummy file on blob or datalake and then add additional columns for Pipeline name, run time, start time, error message etc.. in source tab.
3. Inside Copy activity, Sink - Point to your snowflake table.
4. Inside Copy activity, Mapping tab - Mapp your source and Sink columns accordingly.

Please check below video where author doing same but using dataflow. In your case you can go with copy activity as explained above.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-xna7n33lmc

To know how to access error message of any activity failure. Please check video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_lSB7jaDnG0